# Can I overlap registers in ModBus?

Tags: modbus

I want to use modbus in my project.
I want to use it this way:
if I ask (or transmit) data, I use register number as code, and this code will be generated by script as a CRC16 from the function name.
It may happen, that areas of `RegNum+RequestSize` will overlap on each other, so it will not have the same meaning as in classic modbus, where reading register truely means reading register.

Here is some illustration of what I mean:

[image: classical]

Classic modbus:CMD1(blue) reads data from register 0x00 with size 1, and CMD2(red) reads data from register 0x07 with size 2

[image: my]

My variant: CMD1 "reads data from" register 0x00 with size 3, and CMD2 "reads data from" register 0x02 with size 3. Im device there is no memory blocks overlap, but in the modbus request there is, and if some program creates something like memory amp, there will be a cross over

Is it legal in modern SCADA systems in particular and modern ModBus in general?

P.S. by saying "modern" I mean in modern realizations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Modbus Police Department as far as I know.

If you have control over the devices on both sides of the bus, and you know what you are doing, why wouldn't you be able to?

You seem to have a couple of strange ideas regarding Modbus:

- There is no meaning attached to registers, they are just numbers, you can read them (or write them) any way you want as long as you calculate the CRC of the transactions correctly.
- Modbus is a standard, not a music style. There is no classic and/or modern Modbus. What you do have is devices that comply with the standard and others that are just *inspired* by it.

Obviously, if you are only reading, you will be fine no matter what you do. As soon as you start writing registers you should have a very clear understanding of what you are doing.

Maybe if you post code, somebody would be able to give opinions on whether it is legal, in the sense that you would be able to comply with the [certification requirements](https://www.modbus.org/docs/MBConformanceTestSpec_v3.0.pdf).

From a more philosophical point of view, I can give you an example where I've seen what you describe: imagine a tool with two sensors on each side and four on its front, all of them giving integer values as their readings. On the left, we have values stored in registers 0x00 and 0x01; the right side goes to 0x06 and 0x07 and the four sensors on the front would be stored in registers 0x02 to 0x05. What would I do if I need readings from the front sensors twice as frequently as those coming from the sides? I can send a query to read registers 0x00 to 0x05 followed by another one to read 0x02 to 0x07.

As long as the refresh rate of all sensors and the timings where I need readings are correct for that particular process, my readings are overlapping registers 0x02 to 0x05 but I'm as legal as legal paper can be.